# Why Conda is using a python package outside my environment?

Tags: python, package, anaconda, conda

I just created a new conda environment with python version 3.5.6.  I installed one package called `zipline`, everything OK.  I activated the environment and that looks  OK.  When I run some test code, I get an error that its trying to use a dependency (`numpy`) and it outside my new environment.  It is using the code for numpy from the default python installation on my MacOSX computer, which is a python 2.7 version.  This has got my mind troubled.  Why should it be looking at any packages that aren't installed in my current environment?  So I figure I just needed to install a new version of numpy inside my python 3.5 env.  But when I try to do that, conda tells me all dependencies are already met.

Here's the error.  You can see the first line, it is importing the new package that I installed inside my new env.  Then it is trying to get numpy, and looking is a python 2.7 folder.  From my perspective it seems it should never be looking in that 2.7 folder while my env is activated.  I never installed numpy so it seems it should just say that the module is not found.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "markowitz.py", line 1, in <module>
    from zipline.utils.factory import load_bars_from_yahoo
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda/envs/env_zipline_p36/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zipline/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
```

OK so I tried something.  I exited the environment and uninstalled numpy from conda. I noticed there was still a version of numpy for python 3.5 inside my new environment.  So that is good.  I re-ran the script from inside the new env and didn't get the same error, but I got an error for another package that was trying to reference from the default python 2.7 installation.  So its the same type of error.  Why is it doing this?  It seems it is looking in the default conda packages before looking for the packages in the env?

Here is the new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "markowitz.py", line 1, in <module>
    from zipline.utils.factory import load_bars_from_yahoo
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda/envs/env_zipline_p36/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zipline/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from trading_calendars import get_calendar
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda/envs/env_zipline_p36/lib/python3.5/site-packages/trading_calendars/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .trading_calendar import TradingCalendar
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda/envs/env_zipline_p36/lib/python3.5/site-packages/trading_calendars/trading_calendar.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pandas.tseries.holiday import AbstractHolidayCalendar
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda/envs/env_zipline_p36/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import *
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda/envs/env_zipline_p36/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    import platform
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda/envs/env_zipline_p36/lib/python3.5/platform.py", line 117, in <module>
    import sys, os, re, subprocess
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda/envs/env_zipline_p36/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 127, in <module>
    import _posixsubprocess
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/apple/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_posixsubprocess.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyString_AsString
  Referenced from: /Users/apple/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_posixsubprocess.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/apple/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_posixsubprocess.so
```

Comment: I think we need more info. It may help to know exactly how you installed **zipline** (e.g., conda or pip).  Also, show us all the packages installed in the environment in question, i.e., run `conda list` in the activated env.  Maybe check what PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and other environment variables look like in and out of the env.

Comment: I was able to get around it by using `unset PYTHONPATH` in the command line.  Then running the script stopped looking outside the environment for packages.